# Why don't variables work with "instance" in Django signals?

Tags: django, django-signals

**This works:**

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=MyModel)
def some_signal_function(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):

    instance.field_name = 'foo'

    return None
```

...this will save 'foo' as the field_name.  Simple enough.

**But why doesn't this work:**

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=MyModel)
def some_signal_function(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):

    foo = 'field_name'
    instance.foo = 'bar'

    return None
```

In the second case, django ignores the variable "foo" or treats it as a literal.  Using string method on the variable doesn't help.  Not finding anything in the docs.

Comment: what are you trying to do in the second case exactly? `instance` refers to the row's state before it save. does your row has an attribute `foo`?

Comment: In this case the attribute 'foo' is the field name.  I need to check if the there's data for that field in the instance, with a variable instead of just declaring the name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the second case, django ignores the variable "foo" or treats it as a literal.

It does not ignore that, you simply set the attribute with the name `.foo`, the fact that a variable with the name `foo` exists, and somehow has a string, that does not matter. This is how Python works.

What you can do is make use of the [**`setattr`** builtin function [Pyton-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr):

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=MyModel)
def some_signal_function(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    foo = 'field_name'
    setattr(instance, foo, 'bar')
```

So `setattr(x, 'y', z)` is equivalent to `x.y = z`.

Comment: This.  Thank you.  Along with the corresponding function getattr() this does the trick for my purposes.